# How To resolve server configuration issue

Tags: wordpress, server

In top of my dashboard showing two errors...

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /public_html/couponinuse.com/wp-includes/update.php on line 295

thankz in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is coming from a localhost installation.....

This is due to you having a poor internet connection. I see it often. All it does is slow down your localhost site while it searches for wordpress.org, and that is all. It is simply Wordpress checking the net for updates (and probably fonts as well).

It's just irritating, but no action is needed on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by adding the following line in the bottom of wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error on **Ubuntu OS** using following steps

- open terminal or(Ctrl+t) and type ping api.wordpress.org
- Note the ip address pinging on the terminal. Close the operation by typing Ctrl+c
- Type sudo gedit /etc/hosts and add above ipaddress followed by api.wordpress.org like this (198.xxx.xxx.xxx api.wordpress.org) in the host file

Hope this helps others who runs Ubuntu OS